# How do I display a dependency chain from one package to another?

Tags: dependencies, tree, deb

For example, I want to find out why `monodevelop` does depend on `systemd`.

`apt-rdepends -r systemd` shows all packages that that directly or indirectly depend on systemd:

```
$ apt-rdepends --dotty -r systemd | grep monodevelop
"monodevelop" -> "libgnome2.24-cil";
...
```

`debtree monodevelop` shows all packages `monodevelop` depend on, directly or indirectly:

```
$ debtree monodevelop | grep -- '-> "systemd"'
"libpam-systemd" -> "systemd" [color=blue,label="(= 215-6)"];
...
```

But how do I easily show the chain from `monodevelop` to `systemd`?

Example of one of the chains:

```
monodevelop -> libgnome2.24-cil -> libgnome2-0 -> gvfs -> gvfs-daemons ->  udisks2 -> libpam-systemd -> systemd
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Developed a oneliner for this:

```
$ apt-rdepends --dot -r systemd | perl -ne 'our %chains; if(m!"([^"]+)" -> "([^"]+)"[^"]*;!) { my $c="$2 $chains{$2}"; $chains{$1}=$c; print "$1 $c\n" }'  | grep '^monodevelop '
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
monodevelop libgnome2.24-cil libgnomeui-0 libbonoboui2-0 libgnome2-0 gvfs gvfs-daemons udisks2 libpam-systemd systemd
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` equivalent for your `perl` one-liner:

```
apt-rdepends -dr systemd |
  awk -F\" '/->/{print $2,c[$2]=$4" "c[$4]}' |
  grep '^monodevelop'
```